# Dynamic SQL query with INNER JOIN ON LIKE keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a dynamic SQL query. The variable @NSQL contains the SQL query with a keyword `<<INNERJOINKEYWORD>>` as the last join criteria.

```
  SET @NSQL = 'SELECT * FROM CLIENT
    <<INNERJOINKEYWORD>>'

SET @NSQL = REPLACE(@NSQL,'<<INNERJOINKEYWORD>>',' INNER JOIN #TempTable ON Client.Name = #TempTable.ClientName')
```

This work OK.

Now I am trying to turn this into a dynamic SQL LIKE query as follows:

```
SET @NSQL = REPLACE(@NSQL,'<<INNERJOINKEYWORD>>',' INNER JOIN #TempTable ON Client.Name LIKE ''%#TempTable.ClientName%'')
```

When I do a `SELECT @NSQL`, the text '#TempTable.ClientName' is part of the query, how to make this dynamic?

Comment: should be `LIKE #TempTable.ClientName + ''%''`

Comment: @Squirrel: almost. :) You forgot the leading %.

Comment: Every time I'm using dynamic SQL, I first do `print @sql` before I do `exec(@sql)`. This way, I can see the final result before executing it. That's the easy way to debug dynamic SQL statements, especially if they result in an sql that's easy enough to proof read.

Comment: print @sql is same as what I did to see the dynamic SQL - SELECT @NSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET @NSQL = REPLACE(@NSQL,'<<INNERJOINKEYWORD>>',' INNER JOIN #TempTable ON Client.Name LIKE ''%'' + #TempTable.ClientName + ''%''')
```

However, be aware that you could be introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities with this approach. Since it involves the client's name, the chances are small, but nevertheless it would be good to make sure the client name cannot contain malicious values like `';DELETE FROM CLIENT;--`.